# CORS issue and 415 dont support media response

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, cors

I have read about CORS many times in the past, and understand what it is. I am currently trying to make a POST request to an endpoint that I have been provided, but I keep getting a CORS error.

I have been ensured that the POST request can be made by the owner of the endpoint, so I want to confirm I am not doing anything wrong by checking on this forum.

this is the latest code that I am using:

```
$.post({
   url: "http://working-api-apparently.com",
   data: {
        "name": "Paul",
        "about": "I want to fix this",
        "urls":"['paul.com', 'paul2.com']"
   },
    contentType:"application/json"
});
```

I have also tried using a callback with `jsonp`, but this doesnt work as the endpoint doesnt allow `GET` requests.

The instructions I have been provided are:

```
POST to http://working-api-apparently.com
With Content-Type set to "application/json", and a JSON document as body with the following keys:

"name": Your real name as a String
"about": about as string
"urls": Array of Strings
```

I have tried writing the request in both plain javascript and also using jquery. Can anyone help and let me know what I am doing wrong before I respond by saying it is not working due to a fault on their end.

Also, I am making this request from my local machine, but also tried from a `http:` address

Comment: **JSONP** works **only** for **GET requests** BTW.. And I dont think posting to cross domain is a capability in Javascript by any chance. Please check if POSTing the Data is even Allowed or not.

Comment: how can I check if POSTing is alllowed? I am sure it is, but would be good to confirm?

Comment: I see.. That's not allowed. Use an Iframe that should help.. Try Googling **Iframe image upload** and use the same concept..

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal — "And I dont think posting to cross domain is a capability in Javascript by any chance" — It's always been possible to make cross origin post requests with JavaScript. The problem has been reading the response and even that's been simple since CORS was introduced about a **decade** ago.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — To check is POSTing is allowed: Make a properly formatted request and then see if the browser complains about Access-Control headers being missing.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal — Using the iframe hack is impossible here. You can only use it for form and multipart encoded data. There is no way to generate JSON encoded data from a form.

Answer (score 1):

You are claiming to be sending JSON, but you aren't actually passing JSON.

To do that, you need to encode the data:

```
   data: JSON.stringify({
        "name": "Paul",
        "about": "I want to fix this",
        "urls":"['paul.com', 'paul2.com']"
   }),
```

Fixing that is unlikely to resolve cross origin issues though. It is possible that the instructions are you are following are for a generic REST client and that the server doesn't provide the CORS headers that are required for you to do cross origin requests from JS in a web page. (These are required because you aren't making the request, you are asking the user's browser to make it with the user's identity).

Comment: thanks Quentin, I am aware of this, and had been stringifying it previously, but was still facing the CORS issue. I believe the server doesnt provide the correct CORS headers.

Comment: As mentioned, if the server doesn't give you permission, then you can't do it from the browser.

Comment: can i do it from the terminal without encountering the same issues?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — Yes. You'll only have two parties there, not three. CORS is designed to solve the three party trust problem.